# Custom WooCommerce Price Display: Exact Backend Values on Frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the WooCommerce plugin, and I want the product prices to be displayed exactly as I enter them in the backend. For instance, if I set a price of 500, I want it to appear as 500 on the frontend, without any trailing zeros or decimal places. Similarly, if I enter a price like 456.4, I want it to show as 456.4 on the product page, not 456.40. Additionally, if I enter a price like 34.968, I want it to be displayed as 34.968 on the frontend, preserving the exact decimal value without any automatic formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 10, 2 );

function custom_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    $price = (float) get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_regular_price', true );
    $formatted_price = number_format( $price, 0, '', '' );

    // Check if decimals exist
    if ( strpos( $price, '.' ) !== false ) {
        // Preserves exact decimal places
        $formatted_price = number_format( $price, strlen( explode( '.', $price )[1] ), '.', '' );
    }

    return '<span class="price">' . $formatted_price . '</span>'; // Wrap the price in a span for styling if needed
}
```

I found a solution  but is it safe to use?

Comment: You should replace `$price = (float) get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_regular_price', true );` with the active price using instead `$price = (float) $product->get_price();` as WooCommerce data is progressively migrating to custom database tables.